# Providing descriptive help context for Enums in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, ide

Is it possible to have help context displayed for each individual enum on code drop down display? (i.e. control space ?)

e.g.

```
public enum Moods
{
    Depressed = 1,  ///On Rainy Days use this
    BlownAway = 2, ///On Stormy nights use this
    Ferengi = 3  //Use this for Profit and glory
}
```

and later on in code have the specific enum and it's comment displayed in the code completion drop down when we type : `Moods.`

Comment: @jparaya : I did that but autocmpletion didnt show the description

Comment: What fun to read your enum values :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For intellisense descriptions, use the `<summary>` tag, as in:

```
/// <summary>
/// Various moods
/// </summary>
public enum Moods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// On Rainy Days use this
    /// </summary>
    Depressed = 1,  
    /// <summary>
    /// On Stormy nights use this
    /// </summary>
    BlownAway = 2, 
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this for Profit and glory
    /// </summary>
    Ferengi = 3  
}
```